# Cannot bundle jQuery files in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have 2 js files:

1. jquery.validate.js
2. jquery-1.10.2.min.js
   along with other files I'm using mvc bundling technique to bundle them.

I have a form with a lot of required invisible fields(these fields are needed in other pages).
When I do form.Valid(), it is validating even the invisible fields and says form is invalid even when I fill in all the data.

When I don't bundle it all works fine.
So I think the problem is with bundling those 2 files.
My question would be **why is that is there something with these files we CANNOT bundle?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are including the bundle in a point prior to usage?

Comment: yes, I'm including it prior to usage

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to bundle these files (and others), but in one project, I have them grouped separately.  In other words, I have JQuery-*.js bundled by itself, and have the Validate and other helper files in another bundle.  The main reason I did it this way is because  not all of my screens need the Validate portion, so it's only loaded when necessary.  In another project, I bundle them together.  Works in both cases.

To use the bundled files, in your Razor code, you need something like:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

I would include JQuery bundle before the Validate bundle, if you use separate bundles.  If using one bundle, put the validate last in the bundle list.

Answer (score 0):

you can not bundle both together
because jQuery.validate is dependant on jQuery.

so your jQuery file must load first an than jQuery.validate should load.